# How to Download a Large CSV file with node.js and react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I want to download a Mongo collection (with huge number of records) as a CSV from react through node.js.

Currently what I do is, I load data first in to the Node and after process them I resolve promise. For small collections, this works fine. But when number of records getting higher it returns 502 error after a long time. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Use cursors and stream the response with pipe .Its suitable for processing large data-set and would also prevent memory leaks resulting in system crash.

Comment: You can take a look as example in 
https://itnext.io/using-node-js-to-read-really-really-large-files-pt-1-d2057fe76b33

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic code spinet which helped me to solve the above problem.

```
    const collection = ... ;
    const query = ... ;
    const select = ... ;

    const cursor = mongodb.collection(collection).find(query, select)

    var csv = require('csv');

    transfer(doc) {
    return {
        Address: doc.address,
        State: doc.state.abbreviation
    };
    }

    function(req, resp) {
    const cursor = ...
    // The transfer function (above)
    const transfer = ...;

    const fileName = "Download.csv";

    resp.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; fileame=${fileName}`);
    resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/csv' });

    resp.flushHeaders();

    // Stream the query result 
    cursor.stream()
        .pipe(csv.transfer(transformer))
        .pipe(csv.stringify({header: true}))
        .pipe(resp)
}
```

Comment: can you please explain this line .pipe(csv.transfer(transformer))

Answer (score 0):

Split the process into parts and make use of Redis. Parse the CSV and push each job to Redis queue. start new worker processes in parallel to fetch a job from the queue and processing it. if your system has multiple cores you can use cluster modules to split the worker process. note that process don't have a shared memory.

> Redis connection

```
 var kue = require("kue");

     var queue = kue.createQueue(
      {
        redis: `redis://${redisHost}:${redisPort}`,
        jobEvents: false
      }
    );
```

> Worker Process

```
var clusterWorkerSize = require('os').cpus().length;
var workers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < clusterWorkerSize; i++) {
        var worker = cluster.fork();
        workers.push(worker);
}
```